# Question with constructor in C++ ArrayStack

Tags: c++, arrays

I am in the process of constructing a StackArray. I already have a "Stack.h" implemented with a constructor. I was wondering what I would do in my "StackArray.h" file to use the Stack.h file. I was thinking to use inheritance but it was giving me a error.

My code is as follows:

**Array.h**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <assert.h>

using namespace std;
#ifndef _ARRAY_H
#define _ARRAY_H

template<class T>
class Array{
  private:
    T *a;
    int length;
  public:
    // constructor
    Array (int len){
      length = len;
      a = new T[length];
      for (int i = 0; i < len; i++){
        a[i]=0;
      }
    }
    // destructor
    ~Array()
      {delete[] a;}
    // operator overload
    T& operator [](int i){
      assert (i>=0 && i < length);
      return a[i];
    }

    //get the length of the array
    int arraylength(){
      return length;
    }
};
#endif
```

**ArrayStack.h**

```
#ifndef _ARRAYSTACK_H_
#define _ARRAYSTACK_H_

#include "Array.h"

using namespace std;

template<class T>
class ArrayStack
{
  protected:
    Array<T> a;
    int n;
  public:
    ArrayStack(int len);
    virtual ~ArrayStack();
};


template<class T>
ArrayStack<T>::ArrayStack(int len){
 // I don't know what to do here to implemented constructor from another class.
}

#endif
```

Any suggestion would be great, Thank you
Andy

Comment: This is a question that should be answered by your teacher, tutorial, or book that's teaching you C++. The keywords to ask about are 'initializer lists'

Comment: Side note: `using namespace std;` might produce weird bugs if you accidentally type `array` instead of `Array` or `stack` instead of `Stack`.

Comment: With your current implementation looks like you will need to construct new Array each time you make pop() or push() operation on StackArray. So as were suggested above, use initializer lists, and write two methods for Stack Array - pop() and push()

Comment: Never put a *using-directive* at file scope in a header file.